# запрещен доступ к контейнеру в docker

Tags: docker-compose

Только начала изучать программирование и вот.
При попытки удаление пишет:
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/prune": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
А при попытке остановить поднятые контейнеры пишет:
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 77acd4507bfca1a144f836add4c0f5e2b38c0ca96f766bb509a263180e0b3c31: permission denied
Это при написании команды sudo docker-compose down[image: как выглядит попытка остановить контейнеры]

Comment: Добавьте юзера от которого запускаете в группу docker

Comment: пыталась, не получилось, психанула и переустановила ос. Пока не смотрела сработало ли